# Type mismatch with bounded wildcard ? super Type

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I'm having a problem getting this type conversion working correctly.  My guess is the bounded generic wildcard <? super SomeType> doesn't work with interface implementations.

```
// sample class definitions
public interface IFace<T> { ... } 
public class MyClass<T1, T2> { ... }
public class UtilityClass<T> {
    public List<MyClass<T, ? super IFace<T>>> getList() { ... }
}
public class Actor extends SomeObj implements IFace<TypeA> { ... }

// use...
UtilityClass<TypeA> utility = new UtilityClass<TypeA>();
List<MyClass<TypeA, Actor>> list = utility.getList();

Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<MyClass<TypeA, ? super IFace<TypeA>> to List<MyClass<TypeA, Actor>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuitively, one might try to resolve the issue by making the method generic:

```
public <X super IFace<T>> List<MyClass<T, X> getList() { ... }
```

But this syntax isn't allowed, as it typically doesn't make sense to give a lower bound to type parameters using `super`. See this article for a good explanation of why: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ107

**Edit:**

Looking at your code, I think you may be confusing `super` with `extends` in specifying bounds of a type parameter. It *would* be meaningful if `getList()` returned a `List<MyClass<T, ? extends IFace<T>>>` instead, as this is specifying an *upper* bound on the second type parameter of `MyClass` (in other words that type must be something implementing `IFace<T>`).

As [natix's answer points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8772414/697449), using wildcards in generic return types is discouraged because it effectively hides part the generic type information for the returned object. Instead, make the method generic:

```
public <X extends IFace<T>> List<MyClass<T, X> getList() { ... }
```

Which allows the calling code to specify the type of `X` through type inferrence.

Comment: You are right, thank you. I will remove my answer after a few minutes have passed.

Answer (score 4):

Citing Joshua Bloch's Effective Java 2nd Edition:

> **Do not use wildcard types as return types**. Rather than providing
>   additional flexibility for your users, it would force them to use
>   wildcard types in client code.
>
> Properly used, wildcard types are nearly invisible to users of a
>   class. They cause methods to accept the parameters they should accept
>   and reject those they should reject. **If the user of a class has to
>   think about wildcard types, there is probably something wrong with the
>   class’s API**.

Answer (score 1):

When you start working with generics, a real must-read is [this tutorial](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf). If you read the 'Generics and Subtyping` section on page 4 you will know why you get that error. It has nothing to do with the fact you are using an interface

Comment: The tutorial link seems to be broken. Here's a link to similar info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html